# Scrolling issue when an Editor is Inside the scrollview

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a scrollview and inside the scrollView there is an editor(which has default scrollview property)and when the editor is scrolling and reach to either End/Start point of the editor then the outerView i.e.,the ContentPage has to scroll automatically.
Is it possible to do like this?

Thank you.

Comment: you really should not nest ScrollViews

Comment: @Jason I have modified my question.can you please help me with this.Thank you

Comment: Set the editor height as per the data in editor that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You Can write code like this:

You should take an editor in stacklayout.

```
<ScrollView>
             <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Controls:Label Grid.Row="0" Font="15" Text="{Binding LabelAddress}"/>
                       <StackLayout>
                             <Controls:PlaceholderEditor Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TextAddress}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Margin="{StaticResource MarginTop20}"  Placeholder="Enter Address" PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource LightGray}" AutoSize="TextChanges"/>
                       </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the Reply..But taking the editor inside stacklayout doesn't make any change.Do you set any scrollview properties inside the placeholdereditor renderer for this?

Thanks.

Comment: placeholdereditor renderer is related to a placeholder of an editor.